# Superscript in wxPython RichTextCtrl

Tags: wxpython, subscript, superscript, richtextctrl

I am trying to get wxPython RichTextCtrl to display superscripts.
I have seend some wxWidgets code at

http://wxwidgets.10942.n7.nabble.com/rich-text-and-font-attributes-td23557.html

and also seen the documentation at

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextAttr.html#wx.TextAttr.SetTextEffects

So far, I have got this and it's not working

```
attr = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
attr.SetTextEffects (wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUPERSCRIPT)
attr.SetTextEffectFlags (wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECTS)
#attr.SetTextEffectFlags (wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUPERSCRIPT)
attr.SetFlags (wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECTS)
self.myRichTextCtrl.SetStyle (currentPos, currentPos+len(value1)-1, attr)
self.myRichTextCtrl.WriteText (myString)
```

I know there's a fancytext widget, but it's not practical to switch to fancytext at this point.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `SetStyle` you are applying attributes to text positions that you haven't written yet.

There is an option `SetBasicStyle` and `SetDefaultStyle` which allow you to set the attributes for the whole document or from now on.

Here is a working example.

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rt
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test RichText Superscript')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.rtc1 = rt.RichTextCtrl(self.panel,pos=(10,10),size=(350,90),style=wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.NO_BORDER|wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT|wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT_FACE)
        self.rtc2 = rt.RichTextCtrl(self.panel,pos=(10,110),size=(350,90),style=wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.NO_BORDER|wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT|wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT_FACE)

        self.Show()

        attr_super = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
        attr_super.SetTextEffects(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUPERSCRIPT)
        attr_super.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECTS)
        attr_super.SetTextEffectFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUPERSCRIPT)
        self.rtc1.WriteText("Is this super?")
        self.rtc1.SetStyle (7, 13, attr_super)

        attr_sub = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
        attr_sub.SetTextEffects(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUBSCRIPT)
        attr_sub.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECTS)
        attr_sub.SetTextEffectFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUBSCRIPT)
        self.rtc1.AppendText ("\nIs this sub?")
        self.rtc1.SetStyle (23, 26, attr_sub)
        self.rtc1.AppendText ("\nIs this normal?")

        self.rtc2.WriteText("Is this super?")
        self.rtc2.SetDefaultStyle(attr_super)
        self.rtc2.WriteText("\nIs this super?")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Splendid! Thanks a lot!